# Simple function to change title with JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to code simple function to change the title of the document.

First I tried this code:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zmeň mě!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="newTitle">
    <button type="button" onclick="titleChange()">sub</button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var title, newTitle;
  title = document.title;
  newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;

  function titleChange(newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
  }

  </script>

That didn't work so I was randomly changing it to this:

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zmeň mě!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="newTitle">
    <button type="button" onclick="titleChange()">sub</button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function titleChange(newTitle) {
    document.title = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
  }

  </script>
```

**Why the second one works, but the first one doesn't?**
Thank you so much for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the second one works, but the first one doesn't?

There are two parts to the problem:

1. Where you are getting the new value from.
2. Where you are assigning the value to.

#### Getting the new value

In

```
  function titleChange(newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
  }
```

you are getting the new value from the `newTitle` parameter. But looking at the callsite (`onclick="titleChange()"`) you are never passing a value for the parameter.

Now, above the function you are defining a variable with the same name:

```
newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
```

This doesn't have any effects for two reasons:

The parameter `newTitle` shadows the variable with the same name, thus the value of the variable is never read.

```js
var foo = 42;
function bar(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}
bar(21); // logs 21, not 42
```

The assignment happens only once at page load. At this point in time the input field doesn't have a value yet. Changes to the field later on won't magically update the variable.

---

In your second example you are reading the input field value inside the event handler, i.e. you are getting the current input value at the moment the handler is executed.

#### Assigning the new value

JavaScript is a [*pass by value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) language. That basically means that if you assign the value of a variable or an object property to another variable, a copy of the value is created and assigned. There is no intrinsic connection between the new variable and the "source variable". Thus assigning to `title` won't affect `document.title` in any way.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
bar = 21;
console.log(foo); // still 42, assinging to 'bar' doesn't change 'foo'
```

---

Directly assigning to `document.title`, as in your second example, works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you are starting with JavaScript?

`document.title` is type string.

```js
> typeof(document.title)
"string"
```

So when you assign `title = document.title;` in your first example, you actually copy the string value.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring the title variable in the first try you just stored it's current value in the variable. In the second one you are directly setting document.title to another value. With that approach you don't need to pass the function the newTitle varaible since you aren't using it anyways. Try:

```
function titleChange() {
    document.title = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be about parameter. You gave newTitle parameter to your function when you defined it but you didn't use it while calling your function. You can try this code

```
function titleChange() {
  var title, newTitle;
  title = document.title;
  newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
  title = newTitle;
}
```